# likebox event (iframe)

Tags: facebook, events, iframe, subscribe

im using likebox in iframe

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=
  <?=Facebook::GetConfig('LikeUrl')?>
&amp;width=292&amp;height=290&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;
show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=false&amp;
header=true&amp;
appId=<?=Facebook::GetConfig('appId')?>" 
scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; 
width:292px; height:290px;" allowTransparency="true" id="fbframe"></iframe>
```

how can I know have user pressed like button or no , cuz

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(targetUrl) {
  alert('liked ');
  });
```

does not works

Answer (score 3):

`edge.create` and `edge.remove` events fired only for non Iframe version of Like Button (XFBML and HTML5)

You can easily change your Iframe version other:

```
<fb:like-box href="<?=Facebook::GetConfig('LikeUrl')?>" width="292" height="290" 
             show_faces="true" stream="false" header="true"></fb:like-box>
```